# Plotting envelope of family of curves Maxima

Tags: multivariable-calculus, math-software, maxima-software, envelope

Is it possible to plot envelope of family of curves in Maxima? What is the command. Is there any other free source software?
I need for example the envelope of the family of straight lines $$y+tx=2at+at^3$$